# What does the Indonesian word "ghibtoh" mean?

Tags: hadith, definitions

Please explain to me what is the meaning of the Indonesian word *ghibtoh*, with references to the Quran and hadith.

The article [Hanya Boleh Hasad pada Dua Orang](https://rumaysho.com/1586-hanya-boleh-hasad-pada-dua-orang.html) refers to the hadith:

> لاَ حَسَدَ إِلاَّ فِى اثْنَتَيْنِ رَجُلٌ آتَاهُ اللَّهُ مَالاً فَسُلِّطَ عَلَى هَلَكَتِهِ فِى الْحَقِّ ، وَرَجُلٌ آتَاهُ اللَّهُ الْحِكْمَةَ ، فَهْوَ يَقْضِى بِهَا وَيُعَلِّمُهَا

referenced as "HR. [Bukhari no. 73](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/3/15) dan [Muslim no. 816](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/324)", and is translated to the following in Indonesian:

> Tidak boleh hasad (**ghibtoh**) kecuali pada dua orang, yaitu orang yang Allah anugerahkan padanya harta lalu ia infakkan pada jalan kebaikan dan orang yang Allah beri karunia ilmu (Al Qur’an dan As Sunnah), ia menunaikan dan mengajarkannya.

Simple or detailed answers are welcome.

Comment: Where did you encounter the word "ghibtoh"?  And do you know what language it's in?

Comment: in [here](https://rumaysho.com/1586-hanya-boleh-hasad-pada-dua-orang.html). but sorry, the site is **not** in English. I want to know, where does the term "ghibtoh" is derived? maybe you can reference to me from The Quran / The Sunnah.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good form of jealousy.

In both jealousy and ghibtoh you see someone having something better than you. However:

In jealousy, every time you see the person you hate them publically or in your heart, you mock them, you wish they would not have what they have.

In ghibtoh, you say lucky him. May Allah give him more. May Allah also give me some. I'm  happy for him. I look up to him. etc.

Both are actions of the heart, both can also have physical manifestations ie you **speak** out about it or **do** something about it.

Answer (score 1):

It is as Honey have replied. To add more, `Ghibtoh` or `Ghibtah` is from the the Arabic word `غبطة`, which is defined by [the dictionary](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%BA%D8%A8%D8%B7/) as (my translation):

> To wish the self the bestowed good, without envy, or the wish that the other person loses it.

The word literary coveys the idea of `enclosing` from its other meanings. So as when you do Ghibtoh, you wish you are enclosed in the good the other has, but not them losing it.

*Note*: Don't use the dictionary automatic translation, as it links `غبط` to `envy`, which is the closest, but it is wrong. Not sure if English has a verb similar to this in Arabic.